# Babel 7 inline replace variables

Tags: webpack, electron, babeljs, electron-builder

I have an electron project using electron-webpack which seems to include babel 7.

I have managed to upgrade all my plugins and presets except babel-plugin-inline-replace-variables

any idea what the solution is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `babel-plugin-inline-replace-variables` doesn't support Babel 7.

There's a similar plugin called [babel-plugin-search-and-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-search-and-replace), which will replace strings you choose during babel runtime. Best of all, it supports Babel 7!

First install it to your project as a development dependency:
`npm i babel-plugin-search-and-replace --save-dev`

Then configure it inside of your `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` configuration file:

```
{
    "plugins": [["search-and-replace", {
        rules: [
            {
                "search": "searchedString",
                "replace": "replacement"
            },
            {
                "search": /myRegex/,
                "replace": "replacement"
            }
        ]
    }]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems babel-plugin-inline-replace-variables is not looking like it will support babel 7 in the near future

downgrading electron-webpack to @^1.13.0, and undoing the rest of the beta babel 7 plugin/preset changes fixes my issue...